# Getting Piepkorn GOLD Engine to work with Tango 0.99.9

Tags: d, tango, gold-parser, d1

I can't get the [Piepkorn GOLD Engine](http://goldparser.org/engine/1/d/piepkorn/piepkorn-d-source-v1.0.zip) (released on 2007) to work on my box (DMD 1.056/Tango 0.99.9/Windows 7).

It imports the module **tango.io.MemoryConduit** which is no more present in the Tango version I use.

Excerpt:

```
import
  tango.io.Conduit,
  tango.io.MemoryConduit;

  // ...

this(Conduit c) {    
  auto mem = new MemoryConduit;
  mem.Copy(c);
```

I suppose that **tango.io.Conduit** was replaced by **tango.io.device.Conduit**.

---

## My Question:

What module should I import in place of **tango.io.MemoryConduit** and consequently what construct should I use instead of **auto mem = new MemoryConduit** ?

Answer (score 1):

I found another engine, which is looks like actively developed - http://www.semitwist.com/goldie/
But it requires D2.
Believe to this - [http://forum.dlang.org/post/jc0ic5$18bv$2@digitalmars.com](http://forum.dlang.org/post/jc0ic5%2418bv%242@digitalmars.com) - using D1 now is not a good idea.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I already know Goldie and and it is indeed an excellent project. For the time being I stick to D1/Tango because I like Tango (I am not interesting in non official D2 port). I have posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389509/tango-future-vs-d1-discontinuation) my concern on D1/Tango perpective. Thank you again for your advice, I will certainly have to switch to D2 later on to go further.

Comment: You are always welcome. But, what it wrong with non-official Tango port? (https://github.com/SiegeLord/Tango-D2) it's active, and have only one breaking change (Process class) - how it's author says.